# Zigbee Key-Establishment Process

Tags: certificate, zigbee, key-pair

I am using Zigbee Devices.there was I seen like that once Device Has been joined then Key-Establishment process going on(CBKE process).but I have just small doubt on that.there was server used both attribute like client & server.where the client use only client attribute for key-establishment process.

Why I can't use only server attribute at server side?why this difference we manage in this key-establishment process?so any one can explain me.

Thanks,

BR,
Kanji.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the Smart Energy 1.x profile?

Your device needs to implement the Key Establishment Server if it is capable of acting as the trust centre on the network. The server cluster allows joining devices to initiate key establishment with your ESI.

ALL devices need to have the Key Establishment Client, so that they can initiate key establishment with the trust centre upon joining.

The reason you need both is that your ESI MIGHT be selected as the trust centre for a network, but it might NOT be. There can be multiple ESI's on one network, but only one will be the trust centre. So, in case your ESI joins a network where it is not the trust centre, it needs the client cluster in order to initiate key establishment with the actual trust centre.